# pip ошибка при install google.colab

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

Здраствуйте, столкнулась с проблемой при установке google.colab. Когда я пытаюсь выполнить данную команду:

```
pip install google.colab
```

То у меня происходит куча ошибок, вот фрагмент(Откуда начинаются ошибки):

```
     Building wheel for pandas (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Ksenia\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ksenia\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7dx729mb\\pandas_ca7efc195bca4cb79b5f420b3e7db34c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ksenia\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7dx729mb\\pandas_ca7efc195bca4cb79b5f420b3e7db34c\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Ksenia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-njgk4i41'
       cwd: C:\Users\Ksenia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7dx729mb\pandas_ca7efc195bca4cb79b5f420b3e7db34c\
  Complete output (848 lines):
```

Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать в чем проблема

Answer (score 0):

pip install Cython --install-option="--no-cython-compile"
Думаю этот пакет исправит вашу проблему!

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Не помогло, остались те же ошибки(

Comment: @VictoriaLeshcheko смог установить colab с помощью этой инструкции, как я понял pip архив у них битый. (https://colab.research.google.com/github/d2l-ai/d2l-tvm-colab/blob/master/chapter_getting_started/install.ipynb)